# Why I got the same cipher with different plain text with RSA?

Tags: scala, encryption, rsa

Listing below is my whole code,

```
object RSA {
  def decodePublicKey(encodedKey: String):Option[PublicKey] = { 
    this.decodePublicKey(
      (new Base64()).decode(encodedKey)
    )   
  }
  def decodePublicKey(encodedKey: Array[Byte]): Option[PublicKey]= { 
    scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch.opt {
      val spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey)
      val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
      factory.generatePublic(spec)
    }   
  }
  def encrypt(data: String,key:PublicKey): Array[Byte] = { 
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val file=Source.fromFile(data)
    val stringWords=file.toArray
    val result=new String(stringWords)
    val words=result.getBytes()
    cipher.doFinal(words)
    }
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    println("The keys of RSA " + decodePublicKey("")
    val publicKey=decodePublicKey("")
    val cipher = encrypt("D:\\text.txt",publicKey.get)
    println("cipher is"+ cipher)
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to encrypt a plaintext with RSA. And there are no grammar errors in my code. Question is when I run this, I got the same cipher when I changed my plaintext(D:\text.txt). Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: How do you run the program? Did it recompile correctly?

Comment: Can you please post a full snippet?

Comment: Couple of things: (1) your public key is an empty string. This looks like it would be an error or at least not a usable public key. (2) why are you converting the plaintext that you read to an array then to a string an finally to a byte array? You shouldn't use strings for possibly binary data. (3) you're printing the ciphertext at the end, but this is binary content which is not fully printable. You need to use some kind of binary to text encoding such as Hex or Base64 in order to be able to print the ciphertext. (4) You're saying that you've got the same ciphertext, but you never show it.

Comment: (1)&(4):I had a valid public key but it seems too long to be written here.And   I don't know how to show you  because I am not so familiar with Stack Overflow. (2)The reason I convert the plaintext is because the "doFinal" reads Array[Byte](3)Your answer is quite true,I solve my problem. Thank you very much.